# I cant iterate over an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Am working on a react native project where all users info are stored on the phone using `AsyncStorage` and more than one user is allowed to register using the same phone.

While saving the users' info, I make sure I save them as an array of obejects like this
`[{"username":"Bola","password":"arsenal"},{"username":"friend","password":"enemy"}]`.

Now, in the

> Login page

I tried to retrieve all the users and then use `filter` to retrieve the user who is trying to login to verify whether the user is registered or not. But if I click on the login button, nothing will happen but if I alert the existerUser `alert(existingUser);`, all the registered users will alerted like this `[{"username":"Bola","password":"arsenal"},{"username":"friend","password":"enemy"}]` but if I comment it out, nothing will happen when I click on the

> login button.

This is what I have done so far.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
//import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { Container, Item, Input, Icon, Button, Spinner, Label, TouchableOpacity } from 'native-base';
import { ImageBackground, Image } from "react-native";

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
//import { onChangeTextHandler, login } from '../actions';

function filterByValue(array, string) {
    return array.filter(o =>
        Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())));
}

export default class StudentLogin extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  getStudent = async () => {
    //function to get the value from AsyncStorage
    //let students = await AsyncStorage.getItem('student');
     const existingStudent = await AsyncStorage.getItem("student"); 

    alert(existingUser);// All the students saved records will be alerted
    //let students = existingUser.filter(es => es.username === this.state.username);// Here nothing will happen. I don't know if it dosen't filter anything
    
    // Decided to also use the forEach loop
    let students = [];
    existingUser.forEach(function (u, index) {

    // If the sandwich is turkey, skip it
    if (u === this.state.username;) return;

    // Otherwise log it to the console
    alert(u); // Nothing alerted

});
    // Also decided to use another function I found here on stackoverflow
    let students = filterByValue(existingUser, this.state.username);
    
    if (!students) {
      alert("Email/password combination not correct");
      
    } else {
      alert(students); 
      this.props.navigation.navigate("NewAttendance", { data: students });
    }
    
  render() { 
    return (
            <Container style={styles.contentStyle}>
                <Item inlineLabel style={styles.itemStyle}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="Username"
                style={styles.iconStyle}
              />
                    <Label style={styles.labelStyle}>Username</Label>
                    <Input
           autoCapitalize = 'none'
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    placeholder="Username" 
                    icon={<Icon name="user" />}
                    onChangeText={data => this.setState({ username: data })}
                    label='Username'
                    />
                </Item>
                <Item inlineLabel style={styles.itemStyle}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="lock"
                style={styles.iconStyle}
              />
                    <Label style={styles.labelStyle}>Password</Label>
                    <Input 
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        secureTextEntry
                        onChangeText={data => this.setState({ password: data })}
                        label='Password' 
                    />
                </Item>
                    <Button full onPress={this.getStudent} style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Login</Text>
                    </Button>
            </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I tried this first,

```
//let students = existingStudent.filter(es => es.username === this.state.username);// Here nothing will happen. I don't know if it dosen't filter anything
```

After that, I tried this

```
    function filterByValue(array, string) {
            return array.filter(o =>
                Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())));
        }

let students = filterByValue(existingStudent, this.state.username);
```

Then, I finally tried the

> foreach loop

```
existingStudent.forEach(function (u, index) {
    
        // If the sandwich is turkey, skip it
        if (u === this.state.username;) return;
    
        // Otherwise log it to the console
        alert(u); // Nothing alerted
    
    });
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Its quite common misconception

AsyncStorage can store only **string**

```
const students = [{"username":"Bola","password":"arsenal"},{"username":"friend","password":"enemy"}]

// store like this
await AsyncStorage.setItem("student", JSON.stringify(students))

// retrieve like tis
const rawStudents = await AsyncStorage.getItem("student")
const students = JSON.parse(rawStudents) // you can check if rawStudents is null before parsing
```

Comment: That is the initial step I took, but when I alert it, this is how it display`[object Object], object Object], object Object], object Object]`

Comment: don't you see that there is a JSON.stringify